# Codeigniter url /controller/function/1/3

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, encoding, escaping

I want to transmit in my function a division "1/3" but code igniter consider it like a new argument.

For exemple i want to receive "1/3" and "50"

i'm goding /controller/function/division/number but the division is considered like 2 parameters
There is a function which can escape it ? I tried url_encode but it not works good.

Comment: Explain it little more Or add some code

Comment: well to be very simple , can't you manage it in function itself, I mean you can create function which will take argument like function test(uppernum,lowernum,number)

Comment: Yeah I just wondering if there was a function doing it :)

Comment: you can try converting **`/`** into something meaningful like `divide` or `dvde` i.e `controller/method/1dvde3` and changing it when you already received it on your receiving method, but you really have to be careful secure your script for injections.

Answer (score 0):

Send Input on function like this first create as a string like this "1-/-3" 
or any other chracted

```
    Controller side code like this :
    public function yourfuncname($var){

    $inputrec = str_replace("","-",$var);   //this step gives you 1/3

     //other code as per your requirment.
    };
```

On browser side also add some identified chracters in url link,with the help of javascript or jquery. Create input format as "1-/-3"..Then you able to send these value in a single parameter in codeignter.for further processing

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may want to pass the vulgar fraction ⅓ as html URL-encoded entity `&#8531;`

Answer (score 0):

try this: `url_title(‘1 /3’);`
For more details see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Or an alternate solution can be:

```
**encode** the value before passing
$value = str_replace(’=’, ‘-’, str_replace(’/’, ‘_’, base64_encode($value)));

**decode** the value after receiving
$value = base64_decode(str_replace(’-’, ‘=’, str_replace(‘_’, ‘/’, $value)));
```